# I get "ImportError: cannot import name __check_build" when i ungrade my skearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, centos

My system is centos

```
numpy.__version__= 1.14.3
scipy.__version__= 1.2.2
sklearn.__version__ = 0.19.2
python.__version__ = 2.7.15
```

I want to upgrade sklearn to version 0.20.2 because I want use str data in OneHotEncode

I get **ImportError: cannot import name __check_build** when I use sklearn 0.20.2 after upgrade sklearn, it doesn't work to restart python shell

It can be used normally after I `uninstall sklearn 0.20.2` and `install sklearn 0.19.2`
How can I resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Without posting the full trace of the error I can only suggest:

1) Try to reinstall `scipy`

2) Install sklearn: `pip install -U scikit-learn`